# Congruences between CM and non-CM modular forms

Tags: nt.number-theory, modular-forms

Let $g$ be a cuspidal modular eigenform of weight 2 and level $N$ that has CM, so comes from a Groessencharacter of an imaginary quadratic field $K$. Let $p$ be a prime not dividing $N$.

(1) <strike>Is it possible that $g$ can be congruent mod $p$ to an eigenform that does not have CM by $K$?</strike>

I suspect that this may be possible [EDIT: it definitely is possible], so I'd also be interested in the following more specific question:

(2) Suppose $g$ is new of level $N$ and "$p$-isolated" (not congruent modulo $p$ to any other eigenform of that weight and level). Let $\ell$ be a prime not dividing $N$ that is 1 mod p and split in $K$, and let $g'$ be either of the two eigenforms at level $N\ell$ corresponding to $g$. Can there exist eigenforms of level $N\ell$, congruent to $g'$ mod $p$, that do not have CM by $K$?

Comment: (1) should be easy; for example, let $g$ be the modular form of level $N=32$
corresponding to the CM elliptic curve $y^2=x^3-x$, and take $p=3$ or $p=5$
so there are plenty of non-CM elliptic curves with the same $p$-torsion
structure.  For (2), did you trawl the known tables of modular forms?

Comment: Yes, (1) was a silly question, sorry! For (2), I did do some computer checks, and your question prompted me to make some more; at the second attempt I found an example with g the CM form of level 32, N = 17, and p = 5, but in fact for the special case I have in mind it would suffice to consider ell such that ell = 1 mod p, and I didn't find any examples where this is the case.

Comment: The answer to (2) seems to be Yes too.  
The first candidate for $N\ell$ is $98$, with $N = 49$ the conductor of
the curve $[1,-1,0,-2,-1]$ with CM by ${\bf Z}[(1+\sqrt{-7})/2]$,
and $\ell = 2$.  There's an isogeny class of (non-CM) elliptic curves of
conductor $98$, namely the ${\bf Q}(\sqrt{-7})$ twists of the
curves of conductor $14$, such as $[1, 1, 0, -515, -4717]$.
And indeed the modular forms are congruent $\bmod 2$, because
each curve has a rational $2$-torsion point.  
(Or did you mean to require $p$ odd?)

Comment: Um, never mind: this $\ell$ is not $1 \bmod p$ because I used
the same prime for $\ell$ and $p$.  Anyway, see what the
tables turn up; there aren't that many CM forms to try for $g$.

Comment: @DavidLoeffler Although somehow in an orthogonal direction, I wanted to point out a recent common paper with Nicolas Billerey https://jtnb.centre-mersenne.org/article/JTNB_2018__30_2_651_0.pdf for which your question has somehow been inspirational. We start with a residually dihedral form and, at the cost of putting dome $p$ in the, level we produce a CM form (in char. 0) which is congruent to the first, optimising level and weight. In your setting all forms have prime-to-$p$ level, so it is not the same problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$\newcommand\rhobar{\overline{\rho}}$
$\newcommand\Q{\mathbf{Q}}$
$\newcommand\GL{\mathrm{GL}}$
$\newcommand\F{\mathbf{F}}$
$\newcommand\Frob{\mathrm{Frob}}$

If $\rhobar: G_{\Q} \rightarrow \GL_2(\F) = \GL(V)$ is a (projectively) dihedral representation, then congruences between $\overline{\rho}$ and non-projectively dihedral forms are captured by $H^1_{\Sigma}(\mathbf{Q},W)$, where the adjoint representation of $V$ decomposes as $1 \oplus \chi \oplus W$, and the subscript $\Sigma$ denotes that we are considering the appropriate Selmer group. One can see this by noting that projectively dihedral deformations correspond to deforming the induced character, which (with fixed determinant) comes down to $H^1_{\Sigma}(\Q,\chi)$. The group $H^1_{\Sigma}(\Q,W)$ can certainly be non-zero, even in the minimal case. In your second problem, the assumption amounts to asking (in particular) that $H^1_{\emptyset}(\Q,W) = 0$. By the Greeberg-Wiles Euler characteristic formula, this certainly implies that the dual Selmer group also vanishes. If you now allow ramification at an auxiliary prime $\ell$, then the condition on the dual Selmer group becomes more restrictive, and hence it is still zero. Thus, by the Greeberg-Wiles formula again, we deduce that (with $\Sigma$ indicating no condition at $\ell$):

$$|H^1_{\Sigma}(\Q,W)| = \frac{|H^1(\Q_{\ell},W)|}{|H^0(\Q_{\ell},W)|} = |H^0(\Q_{\ell},W(1))|,$$

The second equality coming from local duality ($W$ is self dual, so its Cartier dual is $W(1)$). So you get new deformations whenever the group on the right is non-trivial. If $\rhobar(\Frob_{\ell})$ has eigenvalues $\alpha_v$ and $\beta_v$ then the eigenvalues of $W \oplus \chi$ are $\alpha_v/\beta_v$, $\beta_v/\alpha_v$, and $1$. So:

1. If $\chi(\Frob_{\ell}) = 1$, you get new deformations if the ratios of the eigenvalues in some order are $\ell$,
2. If $\chi(\Frob_{\ell}) = -1$, then $\rho(\Frob_{\ell})$ has projective order two, and so the eigenvalues of $W \oplus \chi$ are $-1$, $-1$, and $1$, and hence the eigenvalues of $W$ are $1$ and $-1$. Hence you get deformations if $\ell \equiv \pm 1 \mod p$.

In either of these cases, the existence of deformations gives rise to modular forms, assuming (for example) we are in a context in which $R_{\Sigma} = \mathbf{T}_{\Sigma}$. Those lifts can not all be CM, since otherwise one would not see any cohomology coming from $W$.

If you want to insist, for example, that the newforms have level structure $\Gamma(N) \cap \Gamma_0(\ell)$ (rather than $\Gamma_1(\ell)$ or higher powers of the conductor at $\ell$) then you could (for example) insist that $\chi(\Frob_{\ell}) = +1$, that $\ell \not\equiv 1 \mod p$, and the ratio of eigenvalues is $\ell$. Then the only possible local deformations are of Steinberg type, and they exist by 1.

**Edit:** I just saw that you want to insist that $\ell \equiv 1 \mod p$. Assuming that you also want $\Gamma_0(N \ell)$-level structure, I think one might be in good shape if $\rhobar(\Frob_{\ell})$ is (for example) trivial. Note that primes which split completely have relatively small density, so one might not find them by accident. Just to please Noam, here's an example:

$$E:= [0,0,0,-1,0] \ \text{of conductor $32$ with CM}$$
$$A:= [0,0,0,-332,-2752] \ \text{of conductor $32 \cdot 61$ with no CM}$$
$$D:= [0,0,0,-3256,-67984] \ \text{of conductor $32 \cdot 373$ with no CM},$$

and then $E[3] = A[3] = D[3]$.

**Extra:** One can also go the high powered route: Khare-Wintenberger lifting theorems allow one to find global lifts (in the potentially diagonalizable situation in which one is in here) as long as one has local lifts. So a lift which is Steinberg at $\ell$ up to twist at level $\Gamma_0(N \ell)$ will exist (assuming $\rhobar$ satisfies the Taylor-Wiles conditions) as long as $\alpha_{\ell}/\beta_{\ell}$ is $\ell$ or $\ell^{-1} \mod p$. Since the lift will be Steinberg at $\ell$, it won't be CM.

Comment: Thanks for the example :-)  I suppose that this deformation theory cannot in general produce a *rational* modular form satisfying the desired congruence, so it was still not clear *a priori* that you'd find an elliptic curve (as opposed to some more complicated factor of $J_0(N\ell)$ with a subgroup isomorphic to $E[3]$.

Comment: Dear Noam, exactly correct, although since I'm lazy, it was much easier just to look through the Cremona tables. For comparison, the first four primes which split completely in $\mathbf{Q}(E[3])$ are $61$, $313$, $349$, and $373$. (For some reason, I missed the curve of conductor $1952$ on my first try.)

Comment: Regarding your extra statement: doesn't this follow already from Ribet's level raising?

Comment: @Ventullo: Yes it does (oops). In my defense, the KW-argument I give doesn't require Ihara's Lemma (the proof goes through Taylor's Ihara avoidance), and so generalizes well to higher rank groups.  